# How well does a unique hash index perform in comparison to the record ID?

Tags: indexing, orientdb, cqrs

Following CQRS practices, I will need to supply a custom generated ID (like a `UUID`) in any `create` command. This means when using [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com) as storage, I won't be able to use its generated `RIDs`, but rather perform lookups on a manual index using the `UUIDs`.

Now in the [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com) docs it states that the performance of fetching records using the `RID` is independent of the database size `O(1)`, presumably because it already describes the physical location of the record. Is that also the case when using a `UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX`?

Is it worth bending CQRS practices to request a `RID` from the database when assembling the `create` command, or is the performance difference negligible?

Comment: The RID is assigned at writing time, AFAIK. So you can't "request" a RID and then use it: it's not a sequence. My suggestion is to use the UUID. You can write a simple test that loads millions of record and lookup for them using the hash index.

Comment: @RobertoFranchini That's actually a great idea, thanks. The way I "request" the RID now is by creating a document in preparation for the command, then populate it when executing the command. Since I'm doing it in a transaction, the blank document will be discarded if the command fails.

Comment: until the transacion is committed, if I remember right, the RID has the form of `#-1:-1`, a way to indicate record not yet committed. Even if RIDs are unique, I will not rely on them at the applicative level. UUID or any other ways to create a unique id is better than relying on a database internal structure. All IMHO :)

Comment: @RobertoFranchini Ahh right, that could be the case. I have not yet wrapped it in a transaction, so I'll probably end up with `#-1:-1` as RID. Just for kicks, I'm going to write a test program anyway to measure the difference in performance and post it here. Thanks for your comments, they really helped.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the performance of record retrieval based on RIDs and indexed UUID fields using a database holding 180,000 records. For the measurement, 30,000 records have been looked up, while clearing the local cache between each retrieval. This is the result:

> RID: about 0.2s per record
>
> UUID: about 0.3s per record

I've done queries throughout populating the database in 30,000 record steps. The retrieval time wasn't significantly influenced by the database size in both cases. Don't mind the relatively high times as this experiment was done on an overloaded PC. It's the relation between the two that is relavant.

To anser my own question, a `UNIQUE_HAS_INDEX` based query is close enough to RID-based queries.